# Xul - javascript tabs and url

Tags: javascript, xul

I'm training to get the address of all open tabs in firefox with no success. My problem is to open a tab if there's no already open, so I should search an address into tabs, and if there isn't, add one.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to iterate over all tabs, get the URLs and compare them. You can get the [`tabbrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser) element via the global variable `gBrowser`.
It has a property [`browsers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/browsers) which is a NodeList of [`browser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) elements.
You can get the `document` object of each webpage via `browser.contentDocument` and then you can get the `location` object, which is the URL.

So you just have to iterate over the `browsers` node list and extract the URL from the `location` objects.

You can add a new tab via [`gBrowser.addTab()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addTab).

This might be also worth reading: [**Tabbed browser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser).

Comment: great! now works           "var debug = "items: "+  gBrowser.browsers.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < gBrowser.browsers.length; ++i) {
                debug+= gBrowser.browsers[i].contentDocument.domain;  // 
          }
"